# Is it rude to recommend ELL?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, etiquette, english

I think that ELL is one of the most useful SE sites, given that many languages lack their own SO.

When I come across a question written in pretty fluent English, but that is somewhat unclear, is it better to try to answer as best as I can or just leave a pointer to ELL and hope they edit the question to be more clear?

I worry this could be taken as English-speaking elitism and scare ELLs away from SE all together.

Comment: In that scenario, the absolute _best_ thing to do is ask some clarifying comments, in my opinion. If after commenting back and forth to clarify the question, you either still feel or feel more strongly that the user would benefit from the ELL site, maybe bring it up casually and politely. Don't be blunt or make it sound like they _need_ to go there, just point out there's a site for it and it could help them write clearer questions. A lot of times, if the user feels you're actively trying to help, there's a decent chance they'll not get mad about it.

Comment: "written in pretty fluent English, but that is somewhat unclear" - I am confused. Is it unclear because the problem isn't described well, or is it unclear because the English is poor form?

Comment: @Andy, I'm talking about questions that clearly have been well-asked, but in a form of English that is less exact than technical questions should be.  Basically, if one of the sentences looks like it could be a question on ELL, should I give them a link?  Asking like that sort of answers my own question, I guess :)

Comment: What the hell is ELL?

Comment: @Cerbrus English Language Learners: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just like SO is not a "improve my code"  service, ELL is not a "improve my paragraph" service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) is one of the worst sites you can go to if your post is unclear in the use of its language.

From my own experience I can tell that they will not accept re-write/re-wording questions. So if you send users from SO to ELL, they are probably lost forever, sent off from SO and rejected at ELL; not a nice experience.

If the question is in [Dunglish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunglish) (or other variants) and barely understandable, just edit the post for grammar and spelling, and ask in a comment for clarifications. Maybe give a tip to enable the spell-checker in their browser.

In the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) it says *Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.*. This is my best.

There is a blog post on Stack Overflow's [Non-English Question Policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/). I cherry pick the one statement that matches my point: *It is not the community's goal to teach English.*

I'm not here to become fluent in British English, I'm here to get a programming problem fixed. When I need help with my writing style, I'll find a better site, thank you.

Comment: Don't dare to edit this post for grammar or spelling mistakes... that includes you Peter M...

Comment: @TylerH You brave, brave soul...

Comment: @Kendra I fear no flower.

Comment: Dunglish is pretty much a disease that I now have a name for. Coming from the Netherlands I've had very decent training in English in both school but also television/gaming starting from a very young age - I learned English from Transformers G1, He-man and Inspector Gadget before I learned how to write. I also speak it daily. And I still regularly commit English-sin without actually realizing it because I accidentally "Dutch it up". Until I come back to what I've written before and I cringe and facepalm at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow is an English-only site. It's not rude to tell someone this rule, just be polite! Forcing a single language on everyone isn't the best solution, but right now it's the only way to keep our site's content consistent.

Still, I agree with your concern that pointing a user to ELL might be taken as English-speaking elitism. If the meaning is unclear, I prefer to edit the post directly and let the user know why I updated it. They are free to roll back the change if they think you changed the meaning of the post.

Also, there are a couple new sites like [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), and [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) which are for specific languages other than English.

Comment: Do take into account that ELL might not be open for *my question was unclear on SO and they told me to ask here to get it fixed*

Comment: @rene Good point

Comment: @rene I doubt ELL would appreciate that!  But maybe steering the asker towards what they're mis-stating would be acceptable, so they can post that to ELL.

Comment: Upvoted for "edit and comment". The OP will hopefully learn from the corrections. We naturally correct children's use of language, and they are happy to take it on board.